# how connect by works to generate numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

For the documentation, I know `connect by` can be used together with `prior`, in hierarchical queries. But quite often I see it is used to generate numbers:

```
SQL> select level from dual connect by level < 10;
 LEVEL
```

`----------`

```
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9

  9 rows selected

SQL>
```

How it works here ? I mean how it generate 1, then 2, and so on. I can not see a hierarchy here, and `connect by` is not being used with `prior`. This has confused me for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

The query does a linear recursive call.

Level is fake column generated by the recursion which tells the recursion depth of current iteration. The connect by clause does not need to refer to prior, it is condition just like any other which tells 'If this row has level smaller than 10, union it to the result set'